# fedora - audio stops after 1-2 seconds

Tags: audio, pulse-audio

When I play music (youtube, vlc, what-have-you) the audio stops after ~1-2 seconds.

If I then try to replay the music, there is no audio at all.

If I then run `rm -r ~/.config/pulse && pulseaudio -k` and I replay the music, audio is heard for 1-2 seconds, and stops. (which means I am back at square one).

Reboot did not help; I am running "Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid".

Comment: Do `pavucontrol` and/or `alsamixer` give you a clue as to what is happening? Also try `killall -9 pulseaudio  && pulseaudio -v --log-target=stderr` to see pulseaudio log, might see something there.